# Making "git reset" effective without using "--hard" option

Tags: git, git-reset

I am using git reset to navigate backward in my git tree; however, except the time that I use `--hard` option, my files do not get back to their earlier versions. As an example I made a file called f1.txt and in every commit, I added a character to it, but when I use `git reset --mixed` or `git reset --soft` commands, they do not change the content of f1.txt and all the characters are there (although when I use `git log`, I see that the HEAD has moved back).

Comment: This is how `git reset` works. Read more about [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). As the answers suggest, you probably want to use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) or [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (if you are using a version of Git older than 2.23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `git reset` to navigate through your tree.
`git reset` will reset the "stage" (what is committed when you `git commit`). So if you do `git add` and want to undo that, you use `git reset`.
If you do `git reset --hard HEAD` it will also reset the file to the status of `HEAD`.

To navigate through the tree, you need to use `git checkout <branch/commit>`.
It you do not want to checkout the commit, but just get the one file from a previous commit, you can do `git checkout <branch/commit> -- path/to/file`.

Checkout the docs:

- [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
- [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Well, technically, you *can* use `git reset` that way, but it's a bit like using a nuclear powered pogo stick to get around, instead of walking or driving or whatever. Rough on the body. :-)

Comment: yes, I understand git reset is not an appropriate command for the navigation but my question is mostly about the options that are used with git reset. When we use --hard we see the changes in our files; however, with --mixed or --soft our files would be the same as the latest commit.

Comment: Yes, that is what `--hard` does. It changes actual files. Otherwise it only changes what is "staged".

Comment: @amiref does this answer your question? If so, an accept would be highly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better use `git checkout` than `git reset` for navigating. You can use `git checkout` with a commit SHA1.